# Why am I getting an Out of Range error sometimes, and not others?

Tags: excel, vba

I have written some VBA that is supposed to look at the value of cells in the range L28:L41 and if the cell says "Submitted" or "Cancelled", clear the contents of that cell and the three next to it Col I-L). It is supposed to do this on each employee's worksheet (to the same cells).

I have a script that seems to be working, but a few times when I have tested it I have gotten an "Out of Range" error on the "DeleteRow.Select" row of code. Sometimes I get this error, but usually I do not. I have been trying to figure out what specific situations are causing this error, but I can't seem to find a pattern. I'm pretty confident in what I put together because it works most of the time. But, I am going to be sharing this worksheet with other people, so I want to make sure they never get this error. Can you help me understand what is wrong with my code and how to prevent this?

```
    Sub DeleteIssuedRows()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim Employee As Worksheet
For Each Employee In Sheets(Array("Sandra", "Diana", "Caitlin", "Kimberly", "Teresa"))
Set DeleteRng = Employee.Range("L28:L41")
    Dim DeleteCell As Range
    Dim DeleteRow As Range
  For Each Cell In DeleteRng
    If Cell.Value = "Issued" Or Cell.Value = "Cancelled" Then
        Set DeleteCell = Cell
        Set DeleteRow = Range(DeleteCell.Offset(0, -3), DeleteCell)
        DeleteRow.Select
        DeleteRow.ClearContents
    Else
    End If
  Next Cell
Next Employee
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you apply the full name of a range it will give you the range you want, like here

```
Set DeleteRng = Employee.Range("L28:L41")
```

but if you use only Range or Cells objects this can refer to another sheet.

Apply the sheet name for them and you get the required range, like this

```
 Set DeleteRow = Employee.Range(DeleteCell.Offset(0, -3), DeleteCell)
```